# inicializar vector en c++

Tags: vectores

Necesitaría inicializar un vector de 2 dimensiones pero sin datos.
mi código es

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> PnF;
```

eso no da error de compilación pero da error cuando cargo datos

gracias

Comment: perdón el código es

Comment: std::vector<std::vector<double>> PnF;

Comment: Esta zona es para comentarios. Puedes editar la pregunta y colocar ahí el nuevo código.

Comment: Cabe la remota posibilidad de que el error sea debido al **como** estás `cargando datos`. ¿ Sería demasiado pedir que mostraras **exactamente** lo que estás haciendo ? Me permito sugerirte que consultes lo que es un [mcve]. Un saludo.